# How to check if element is ready to click

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, automation

I want to explicitly wait till my element is enabled to click on screen.
But currently what happened is element is visible but due to loading symbol driver is not able to click element & code fails. If I use implicate wait then code works. any suggestions

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0,0,60));
wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementSelectionStateToBe(By.XPath(GPDNav),true));
// wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(GPDNav)));
IWebElement gpdNav = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(GPDNav));
gpdNav.Click();
```

Comment: in expected condition we will something like elementtobeclickable... Can you check that?

Comment: Not working that too..Already tried..

Comment: var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
var clickableElement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By.Id("id")));

Comment: Already use below code
  
  `wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath(GPDNav)));`

Comment: Is the above lines not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for the loading element to go off. Find the xpath of the loading element and place it in below code and try it. We have same kind of loading symbol in our application and it is working fine after waiting for invisibility of that loading element.

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0,0,60));
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath of loading symbol"));
wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementSelectionStateToBe(By.XPath(GPDNav),true));
// wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(GPDNav)));
IWebElement gpdNav = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(GPDNav));
gpdNav.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using two explicit waits, First one to wait until the "loading" symbol disappears and the second one to wait until the "button" is clickable.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[loading]")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[button]")));
```